How to do rewrite/redirect using Nginx
I am relatively new to using Nginx. All these while have have been using Apache2 .htaccess for URL rewrite and redirect. Need a few pointer here as to how I can have the following .htaccess condition to be working in Nginx
RewriteRule ^modules/?$ modules.php?type=modules [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?type=user&action=$1&id=$2 [L]

The URL would be https://example.com/modules and it would redirect to a file in the root directory modules.php (there is no folder by the name of modules)
As for the other one it is like https://example.com/user/view/1213432. This would also redirect to a file in the root directory user.php. For /view/1213432 are both variable with the param action=view and id=1213432.
The problem I am having is that it keep pointing to a folder by the name "modules" and also folder by the name "user".
Some examples on how to solve this could help me to learn more. I tried those .htaccess to Nginx converter and they are not working.
Currently the configuration file contain the below:
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /modules/ {
        rewrite ^/modules/?$ /modules.php?type=modules last;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    
    
    charset utf-8;
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


"The problem I am having is that it keep pointing to a folder by the name "modules" and also folder by the name "user"." - Please include the relevant section of your Nginx config.

I have edited my question and added the current configuration from Nginx
